# Can FullCalender be configured with TimeSlots: Morning, Afternoon & Evening

Tags: fullcalendar, timeslots

I would like to configure FullCalendar to have just 3 timeslots per day for;

- Morning   (9:00 - 12:00)
- Afternoon (13:00 - 16:00)
- Evening   (17:00 - 20:00)

Is this possible?
If so, how would it be done?

Comment: No it's not possible. Timeslots must a) all be equal in length (you've covered that) and b) be contiguous without any gaps between slots - you don't meet this requirement. Instead I suggest using the Business Hours or Background Events features to block out the periods where you don't want any events, and also use the various hooks provided (e.g. selectAllow) to control which start times can be selected.

Comment: So would it work if I changed my requirements to match your criteria? e.g.
.
- Morning (8:00 - 12:00)
- Afternoon (12:00 - 16:00)
- Evening (16:00 - 20:00)

Comment: They're not my criteria, they're fullCalendar's! But yes that should work. Use the `slotDuration` setting to control it - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration.

Comment: Ok, I can make that work. Thanks. +1